# SaveFileDialog, file does not exist

Tags: c#, .net

I have to process an XML file (I am choosing a file with OpenFileDialog [code not present here] and when I click the second button the XML is processed to show a tree structure of that XML that has to be saved in the other file). But when I use SaveFileDialog , I want to enter a file name of the file which does not exist yet. How should I do that if I enter the filename that does not exits , an empty file will be created ?

```
       private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        SaveFileDialog fDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
        fDialog.Title = "Save XML File";
        fDialog.FileName = "drzewo.xml";
        fDialog.CheckFileExists = false;
        fDialog.InitialDirectory = @"C:\Users\Piotrek\Desktop";

        if (fDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(fDialog.FileName.ToString());
        }

        string XMLdrzewo = fDialog.FileName.ToString();
        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(XMLdrzewo);
        //// some code processing xml file
        /// not ready yet, have to write to that file the tree
        //structure of  selected XML file

        textBox2.Text = File.ReadAllText(XMLdrzewo);
```

When file does not exist I get FileNotFoundException was unhandled.

Comment: Which line throws this exception?

Comment: I think I got it:
File.Create(filename).Dispose(); befor MessageBox.Show(fDialog.FileName.ToString());

Comment: You're not actually saving anything to the File before trying to load in with `XDocument.Load(XMLdrzewo)` - `SaveDialog` does not automatically create the file - you actually have to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the code that creates your filename should be inside the if statement.

```
if (fDialog.ShowDialog == DialogResult.OK)
{

}
```

Then, you need to create a file first, eg var `stream = File.Create(filename)`. Then you can fill that file with the "to be created stuff" and store the xml part in your newly created file.

Something like:

```
if (fDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{

    using (var newXmlFile = File.Create(fDialog.FileName);
    {
           var xd = new XmlDocument();
           var root = xd.AppendChild(xd.CreateElement("Root"));
           var child = root.AppendChild(xd.CreateElement("Child"));
           var childAtt = child.Attributes.Append(xd.CreateAttribute("Attribute"));
           childAtt.InnerText = "My innertext";
           child.InnerText = "Node Innertext";
           xd.Save(newXmlFile);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is using {} constrution for ?

Comment: that helps you in disposing the object created in the using statement. you don't have to use it, but it saves you to remember writing stream.dispose and stream.close when you are done with the file interaction

Comment: Ok, and do u have and idea how to save an xml tree to a file:
i.e:
<Videos>
  <Video>
    <Title>The Distinguished Gentleman</Title>
    <Director>Jonathan Lynn</Director>
    <Actors>
      <Actor>Eddie Murphy</Actor>
      <Actor>Lane Smith</Actor>
      <Actor>Sheryl Lee Ralph</Actor>
      <Actor>Joe Don Baker</Actor>
    </Actors>
    <Length>112 Minutes</Length>
    <Format>DVD</Format>
    <Rating>R</Rating>
</Videos>
 so that I have in the other file:
Videos
---Video
------Tite
------Director
------Actors
------------Actor
------Length
------Format
------Rating

Comment: maybe you should make a new question for it, and google a bit before you ask questions. I updated the answer with the basics of creating a new xmldocument and save it to your filestream. I hope it helps. And accept the answer as answer to your question if the original question is answered so that others know they don't have to look into it anymore. hope this helps. cheers